# HTML Tags are not rendering in the Gmail - Using PHP language

Tags: php, email, gmail

I have used used the PHP Language for Sending the email and HTML tags are not rendering in the gmail account sometimes.I have used Content Type  as - `charset="iso-8859-1"` I have attached the image.

And also am receiving the Message ID, which should not be come in the mail.

[image]

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to upload an image yet... And please post your code too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend/use php built in mail() function to send and receive emails. Use php open source libraries like PHPMailer and SwiftMailer. I have been using PHPMailer after facing many issues when using mail() alone. Very easy to implement and has lots of features. You don't have to spend your valuable time for email sending related development.

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: Shall I use this in kohana framework ? because am using the kohana framework only

Comment: Use the default module in Kohana or use those libraries (it should work). But I have not tried Kohana in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML isn't rendering, that usually means the headers weren't set properly.

Try this:

```
<?php 
//change this to your email. 
$to = "m@m.com"; 
$from = "m@m.com"; 
$subject = "This is HTML email";  
$message = "
    <b>htmlemail....</b> <br>
    <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>"; 

// To send the HTML mail we need to set the Content-type header. 
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0rn"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1rn"; 
$headers  .= "From: $from\r\n"; 

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
echo "Message sent.."; 
?>
```

From http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=416467

Comment: the same thing i have used @Justin. but no result.

Comment: So if you copy/paste the above code and run it (changing only your email) it doesn't show as an HTML email?

Comment: Yes @Justin. Whether issue is based upon any configurations in SMTP ?